# XCode7.2.1 のデバッグエリアで変数等の詳細が表示されません。表示させる方法をご存知のかたいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記画像はとあるアプリをデバック起動させている時のものです。
普通ならこのウィンドウにメモリアドレスやら値やら等が表示されるのですが、
このアプリに限り表示されません。
最初はコンパイルの最適化オプションが原因かと思ったのですが、-O0 で設定されており問題ないようです。
xcodeのバグかなとも思うのですが、解決策をご存知の方いらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらで現象が再現できないので、『こうしたら良いのではないか？』と思える対処方法をいくつか提案します。

1. プロダクトのクリーン
   Xcodeのメニューから[Product] - [Clean]でクリーンを実行
2. Build Folder全体の削除
   optionを押した状態で、メニューから[Product] - [Clean Build Folder]を実行
   [image: Clean Build Folder]
3. プロジェクト全体を作り直す
4. Xcodeを再インストール
5. OSを再インストール
6. デバッグを諦める

Comment: ２：Build Folder全体の削除
optionを押した状態で、メニューから[Product] - [Clean Build Folder]を実行

で解決しました！　ありがとうございます！